# Python3 requests post correctly but get nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python3 requests post correctly but get nothing

```
    data = {
    'divn_andr': str(instance.DIVN_ANDR),
    'divn_andr1': str(instance.DIVN_ANDR1)
     }
 requests.post(url, data=data)
```

getting error on server

```
  request.POST   <QueryDict: {}>
  request.body  "B"
  json.loads(request.body.decode()) Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your server is expecting json formatted body but you are sending form data so to fix it you should send your request like this:

```py
data = {
    'divn_andr': str(instance.DIVN_ANDR),
    'divn_andr1': str(instance.DIVN_ANDR1)
     }
requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Note the usage of the `json` argument instead of `data`.